# TikZ: add options to existing style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

within `\tikzset{...}` I defined

```
row 1/.style={
    nodes={
        fill=black,
        text=white,
        %font=\bfseries
    }
}
```

such that for every table/matrix the first row is black with white text.
When I now manually add

```
row 1/.style={nodes={text height=1em, text depth=3em}}
```

to a specific matrix the other options I used within the `tikzset (fill=black, text=white)` are gone, so I would have to write them again in that `row 1/.style`:

```
row 1/.style={nodes={text height=1em, text depth=3em, fill=black, text=white}}
```

Is it possible to just ADD the 2 options above to the already defined ones?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As mentioned in section **82.4.4 Defining Styles** of the TikZ manual (for version 3.0.1a, dated 29 Aug 2015), you can use `stylename/.append style={<options>}` to append to the end of an existing style. (There is also `.prefix style` which prepends to the style.)

So for your specific case, use

```
row 1/.append style={nodes={text height=1em, text depth=3em}}
```

(That this works also relies on the fact that `nodes` is a shorthand for `every node/.append style={}`.)

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{row 1/.style={
    nodes={
        fill=black,
        text=white,
        %font=\bfseries
    }
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] { a & b \\ c& d \\ e & f \\};
\end{tikzpicture}

\tikzset{row 1/.append style={nodes={text height=1em, text depth=3em}}}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of nodes] { a & b \\ c& d \\ e & f \\};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]